# Can't write in a .plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a little app that have by default youtube as homepage. You can change it in a little menu, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Here's the code

```
viewController 

.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *array;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *string1;
-(NSString *) dataFilePath;
- (IBAction)settings:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)home:(id)sender;

@end

.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "settings.h"


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize array;
@synthesize string1;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

    if ([string1 isEqual:@"youtube"]) {
NSMutableArray *Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[Array addObject:@"http://www.youtube.com"];
[Array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

    }

NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath]; 
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{ 
    array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
  [webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:string]]];

}                   

-(NSString *) dataFilePath
{ 
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0]; 

    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"url.plist"];
    string1 = @"youtube";

}

- (IBAction)settings:(id)sender {
    settings *NView = [[settings alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:NView animated:YES];

}

- (IBAction)home:(id)sender {
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath]; 
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    { 
        array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    }
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"%@\n",string);
    [webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:string]]];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end

Settings //here's the menu where I can change the homepage

.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface settings : UIViewController{
    ViewController *viewCont;
    IBOutlet UITextField *field;

}
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)setHP:(id)sender;

@end

.m


#import "settings.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation settings

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    field = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)setHP:(id)sender {

    NSMutableArray *Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [Array addObject:field.text];
    [Array writeToFile:[viewCont dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [viewCont.string1 initWithString:@"other" ];
    NSLog(@"%@\n", viewCont.string1);// HERE XCODE SAYS string1 = null!!! WHY?

}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

So anyone knows what am I doing wrong? Please help me, I have searched around the web for 4 days and I didn't find anything!

Comment: Jaun, you need to be a lot more specific about your problem: Where does this go wrong? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is the .plist file saved correctly but not loaded? Are the contents being read wrong? Help us help you.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to change the homepage, because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand well your problem but i notice that you are not initializing `viewCont` in the `setHP:` action.

try to add this line:

```
ViewController *viewCont=[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

just before

```
[viewCont.string1 initWithString:@"other" ];
```